# How does gravity affect entanglement?

Tags: gravity, quantum-entanglement, decoherence

Hypothetically an entangled pair of atoms are placed inside two similar satellites orbiting at the same altitude, one of the satellite will then slow its speed and descend towards the surface of Earth. Assume we can manage to negate decoherence, what will happens to the pair whereby both are experiencing different gravitational effect?

---

Comment: I see that someone wants to close because the question is not clear. Would you mind improving it? I thought you were asking if relativistic effects like changing the velocity of the two atoms and their gravitational red-shift would destroy the entanglement. Is that what you are trying to ask? I think that's an interesting question (which may already have an answer, but I didn't look).